# print list of all numbers from 1 to 100, skip numbers divisible by 3 or 5

Tags: python, list, numbers, python-3.6, subtraction

```
a = range(1,101)

mylist = [num for num in a if num%3==0 or num%5==0]


print(mylist)
```

Here I am getting a list of 3 or 5 multiples. But how can I get a list without these?

Comment: Did you try inverting the condition?

Comment: Look for "fizz buzz" codes, available in all languages, and just adapt to your divisors

Answer (score 2):

You can simply invert your condition as you get the exact opposite of what you want. Instead of "if is a multiple of 3 or 5", you want "if is not a multiple of 3 and not a multiple of 5".

This will produce what you want:

```
a = range(1,101)

mylist = [num for num in a if (num % 3 != 0) and (num % 5 != 0)]

print(mylist)
```

Comment: @d_kennetz Using `and` removes multiples of each value whereas `or` will remove numbers that match both conditions. I.e. `or` will allow numbers such as `9` and `10` in the list but exclude `30`

Comment: Why the choice to use `not` over `!=`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, hahaha good catch, I'm a bit rusty. Have edited that in

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that 0 is False and other integers are True.

```
mylist = [num for num in a if num % 3 and num % 5]
```